# Google AppEngine dynamic loading, ImportError: No module named pip._vendor.requests.status_codes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, importerror, dynamic-loading, python-importlib

I get the following error when i try to implement some kind of dynamic class loading using __import__ ...:

```
No module named pip._vendor.requests.status_codes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File"/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ticatestdev/2.386059027148196174/tica/tasks.py", line 36, in post
    m = __import__(handler['module'], fromlist=[handler['name']])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ticatestdev/2.386059027148196174/tica/sources/processors.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.status_codes import codes
  ImportError: No module named pip._vendor.requests.status_codes
```

... or importlib.import_module :

```
No module named pip._vendor.requests.status_codes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ticatestdev/2.386058813285719320/tica/tasks.py", line 36, in post
    m = importlib.import_module(handler['module'])
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ticatestdev/2.386058813285719320/tica/sources/processors.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.status_codes import codes
  ImportError: No module named pip._vendor.requests.status_codes
```

I import importlib of course.

I deploy my program on the Google AppEngine server to test it (I have a production URL and a Development URL).

Here is the code :

```
import importlib
import json
import logging
class Process(handlers.BaseHandler):
def post(self):
    parameters = json.loads(self.request.get('parameters'))
    if parameters:
        if 'handler' in parameters:
            handler = parameters['handler']
            m = __import__(handler['module'], fromlist=[handler['name']])
            #m = importlib.import_module(handler['module'])
            task_handler = getattr(m, handler['name'])(parameters)
            #task_handler = getattr(m, handler['name'])(parameters)
            task_handler.startProcessing(parameters)
        else:
            logging.error("python.tasks.Process(): No handler information provided!")
    else:
        logging.error("python.tasks.Process(): No parameters provided!")
```

and the parameters contents:

```
{"dictionary_list": [...], "handler": {"name": "SourceProcessingHandler", "module": "sources.processors"}, "command": "process", "fsm": {}, "language_code": "ja"}
```

I could not find a similar error on google,

I wonder now if I am not wasting my time trying to outsmart myself with this complex solution ...

May be I should use a simple dictionary associating a name to the python classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tica/sources/processors.py` file appears to be part of your application. If so it explicitly depends on the `pip` package, which doesn't appear to be part of the standard python library and is not included in the GAE [Runtime-Provided Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en#runtime-libraries). This means it would need to be [vendored in](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en#vendoring).

All the packages/modules that you want to dynamically load together with all their dependencies may similarly need to be vendored in.

I'd also add a lot more sanity checks before attempting to execute the dynamically loaded code. At least catching and handling `ImportError`.

Side note: just in case `task_handler.startProcessing(parameters)` can take too long and cause `DeadlineExceededError` for the `post` request you may want to delegate the execution onto a task queue or a backend execution module instead.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to check your answer, I found the error before you answered but I think your answer would have been helpful anyway ;) I had an "from pip._vendor.requests.status_codes import codes" import line appear out of nowhere in the file, as far as I can tell. I must have triggered something in eclipse to make it appear but I can't imagine how ... Thank you